# Django View/Template - selecting only two fields from a model

Tags: python, django

I have a model with around 20 fields, of which from a particular view i only need return two fields, 'location' and 'id'. (I'm under the impression resources will be saved if I only pass the two fields instead of all 20)

My code and error is below, I'm assuming I'm seeing this error because I am not sending any data?

Thanks

views.py

```
def showroom_list(request):
    modelShowrooms = ShowroomConfigData.objects.values_list('location', 'id')

    return render(request, 'service/showrooms.html', {
        'Showrooms': modelShowrooms,
    })
```

showrooms.html

```
{% extends 'home/base-wide.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div id='content-body'>
    {% include 'service/sidebar.html' %}
        <div class="float-left">
        {% for item in Showrooms %}
            <a href="{% url 'service:showroom_detail' item.id %}">{{ item.location }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

error:

```
Reverse for 'showroom_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'service/showroom/?P<question_id>[0-9]+$']
```

on line:

```
<a href="{% url 'service:showroom_detail' item.id%}">{{ item.location }}</a>
```

Comment: I think, url-pattern should be: `^service/showroom/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)$` (you forgot brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to fetch the id and location fields, you can use [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only)
. This still returns model instances.

```
modelShowrooms = ShowroomConfigData.objects.only('location')
```

You don't need to specify the primary key `id`.

Make sure that you include all of the field names. If you access a field that is not included in the list of field names, then Django will do a new query to fetch the value.

Comment: ive added this and im still getting the same error, changed (item.shworoom to item.location, was a typo)

Comment: sorted (missing () from the id)

Answer (score 1):

`values_list` will only provide you with a list of `tuples` containing these values. You cannot access `item.id` etc. using that.

You need to get the elements of the tuple:

```
{% for location, item_id in Showrooms %}
    <a href="{% url 'service:showroom_detail' item_id %}">{{ location }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And, you are also accessing `showroom` which is not present in the `value_list`. I suppose you want `location` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In most language you can do this:

```
for k,v in list:
   print v
```

so,

```
{% for location, id in Showrooms %}
 <a href="{% url 'service:showroom_detail' id %}">
   {{ item.showroom}}
 </a>
{% endfor %}
```

As people mentioned, values_list returns a list of values. so,

```
print modelShowrooms
```

In django, there are many ways to loop list. all(), values(), get_values()

Please refer to document, especially in first paragraph..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/